# Need a VBScript for Open a local Image File by using Command prompt

Tags: vbscript

I need a Vbscript that should open a image file from my PC and after some minutes that will get close automatically. I am planning to run the script through Command prompt any help is much appreciatable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be easier to do this with an [HTML Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471(VS.85).aspx) rather than plain VBScript. Here's a sample HTML app that display an image in a popup window that automatically closes after 5 seconds (you didn't say whether you needed to have the image name and the timeout parameterized, so I assume they are predefined and can be hard-coded):

```
<html>
    <hta:application id="oHTA"
        border="none"
        caption="no"
        contextmenu="no"
        innerborder="no"
        scroll="no"
        showintaskbar="no"
    />
    <script language="VBScript">
        Sub Window_OnLoad
            ' Resize and position the window
            width = 500 : height = 400
            window.resizeTo width, height
            window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2

            ' Automatically close the windows after 5 seconds
            idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 5000)
        End Sub
    </script>
<body>
    <table border=0 width="100%" height="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="middle">
                <img src="myimage.jpg"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Simply paste this code into a text editor, replace the window width and height, the timeout and the image file name with your values and save as an .HTA file (e.g. *showimage.hta*).

HTAs can be run from command line by their name, e.g.

```
showimage.hta
```

To run an HTA from VBScript, you can use the [`WshShell.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(VS.85).aspx) method:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run "showimage.hta"
```