# How to display an image in vbscript?

Tags: image, vbscript

I would like to write a code to display and image for every 20 minutes using Vbscript. Is it possible to load the images using VBscript? I've found the `LoadPicture()` would be an option.

***The image should pop-up once in every 20 minutes in my desktop window.***

How to use it? Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are tons of free wallpaper changers out there. Any particular reason why you'd want to implement the umpteenth one (and in VBScript to boot)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Actually I'm trying to create an application which pops up a gif image of a blinking eye every 20 minutes with a message "Please blink your eyes and see an object which is 20 feet away from you." I thought I could do it with VBScript.

Comment: @Arun - Have you tried using Windows Task Schedule to execute your vbs ... you can schedule it to run after every 20 minutes I believe

Comment: @Pankaj, could you please gimme an example?

Comment: @arunpandiyarajhen - Have posted a possible solution in Answers. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Related: [Need a VBScript for Open a local Image File by using Command prompt](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1221145/113116)

Answer (score 4):

Ok Arun. Here is what I did

1. Create a VBS file with the following code

   ```
   Set objExplorer = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   With objExplorer
       .Navigate "about:blank"
       .Visible = 1
       .Document.Title = "Show Image"
       .Toolbar=False
       .Statusbar=False
       .Top=400
       .Left=400
       .Height=200
       .Width=200
       .Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='C:\Users\pankaj\Desktop\a.jpg'>"
   End With
   ```
2. Go to Window's Task Scheduler and create a task

   - Create a Trigger for 20 minutes - repeated Daily
   - Specify Action as Start a program -> %systemroot%\system32\cscript.exe -> in
     arguments give the VBS file's location

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try for this vbscript :

**LoadImage.vbs**

```
Option Explicit
If AppPrevInstance() Then 
    MsgBox "There is an existing proceeding !" & VbCrLF & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptName),VbExclamation,"There is an existing proceeding !"    
    WScript.Quit   
Else
    Dim ws,fso,Srcimage,Temp,PathOutPutHTML,fhta
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Temp = WS.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%Temp%")
    PathOutPutHTML = Temp & "\image.hta"
    Set fhta = fso.OpenTextFile(PathOutPutHTML,2,True)
    Srcimage = "http://img.xooimage.com/files86/6/3/b/encode-decode-37ceb55.jpg"
    Do
        Call LoadImage(Srcimage)
        ws.run "mshta.exe " & PathOutPutHTML
        Call Pause(20)
    Loop
End If
'********************************************************************************************************
Sub LoadImage(Srcimage)
    fhta.WriteLine "<html>"
    fhta.WriteLine "    <hta:application id=""oHTA"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        border=""none"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        caption=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        contextmenu=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        innerborder=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        scroll=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "        showintaskbar=""no"" "
    fhta.WriteLine "    />"
    fhta.WriteLine "    <script language=""VBScript"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "        Sub Window_OnLoad"
    fhta.WriteLine "            'Resize and position the window"
    fhta.WriteLine "            width = 760 : height = 580"
    fhta.WriteLine "            window.resizeTo width, height"
    fhta.WriteLine "            window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2"
    fhta.WriteLine "            'Automatically close the windows after 5 seconds"
    fhta.WriteLine "            idTimer = window.setTimeout(""vbscript:window.close"",10000)"
    fhta.WriteLine "        End Sub"
    fhta.WriteLine "    </script>"
    fhta.WriteLine "<body>"
    fhta.WriteLine "    <table border=0 width=""100%"" height=""100%"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "        <tr>"
    fhta.WriteLine "            <td align=""center"" valign=""middle"">"
    fhta.WriteLine "                <img src= "& Srcimage & ">"
    fhta.WriteLine "            </td>"
    fhta.WriteLine "        </tr>"
    fhta.WriteLine "    </table>"
    fhta.WriteLine "</body>"
    fhta.WriteLine "</html>"
End Sub
'**********************************************************************************************
Sub Pause(Min)
    Wscript.Sleep(Min*1000*60)
End Sub  
'**********************************************************************************************
Function AppPrevInstance()   
    With GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")   
        With .ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE CommandLine LIKE " & CommandLineLike(WScript.ScriptFullName) & _
            " AND CommandLine LIKE '%WScript%' OR CommandLine LIKE '%cscript%'")   
            AppPrevInstance = (.Count > 1)   
        End With   
    End With   
End Function   
'**************************************************************************
Function CommandLineLike(ProcessPath)   
    ProcessPath = Replace(ProcessPath, "\", "\\")   
    CommandLineLike = "'%" & ProcessPath & "%'"   
End Function
'**************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set objExplorer = CreateObject ("InternetExplorer.Application")
Do
Wscript.sleep 1200000
with objExplorer
.Navigate "about:blank"
.Document.Title = "title goes here"
.ToolBar = 0
.StatusBar = 0
.Left = (intHorizontal - 200) / 2
.Top = (intVertical - 400) / 2
.Width = 200
.Height = 400
.Visible = 1             

.Document.Body.Style.Cursor = "default"

.Document.Body.InnerHTML = "<img src='C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Virus\Image.jpg'>"
End With
Loop
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: Seems like the code createsObject called InternetExplorer, then sets attributes like page title & what is displayed by the object ('the image'), every 1200000 milliseconds (20 minutes). Code seems to be in VBscript, requested in question.