# How do I close a window by clicking on it?

Tags: vbscript, hta

A few years ago Helen offered a simple [script to display a picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221145/need-a-vbscript-for-open-a-local-image-file-by-using-command-prompt).  It was just what I was looking for. The picture window closes by itself after a certain amount of time. Now I would like to change that so that it only closes when clicking on it. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change that HTA as follows:

remove line `idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 5000)`

replace `<body>` with `<body onclick="vbscript:window.close">`

UPD: and to slide the picture across the screen by dragging with right | mid button just add:

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
        (function() {
            var x0,y0;
            document.onmousemove=function () {
                if ((event.button!=0)&&(event.button!=1)){
                    window.moveBy(event.x-x0, event.y-y0);
                    return false;
                }
                document.body.style.cursor='auto';
            }
            document.onmousedown=function () {
                if (event.button!=1){
                    document.body.style.cursor='move';
                    x0=event.x;
                    y0=event.y;
                }
            }
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Works great. Thank you very much.  Is there similarly a way in which I can slide the picture across the screen by dragging?  Or should that be another question?

Comment: @Pablo678 Yes, that should be another question.