# Easy way to set up a splashscreen for my Windows app?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, window, vbscript

I am making an app (software) for Windows. To run the app the user clicks on a .vbs file (or a shortcut to it). It takes a while to load up the main screen so I was wondering what's the easiest way to create a splash screen for my app? All it needs is to display an image on screen while it is waiting for the main window to appear. Once the main window appears, the splash screen can close.

Is there way a way to do that with a .vbs file? Happy to venture into Python or anything else but it needs to be simple to set up.

All I could find was related to Android which isn't relevant for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [HTML-application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536471%28VS.85%29.aspx) (hta-file) to do this. Have a look at [this description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1221626/2523663).